# Best way to Update a strongly typed View(MVC 3.0)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strongly typed Category View, showing all Category (in a grid) ... 
Under that grid I have the fields to Add/Edit a new Category details: several textbox and radiobox, like :
- Category Name
- Category Description
- Category Imagem 
etc

So, When the user select a Category on Grid, it fills the fields via JQuery Ajax...

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/Category/Get',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            idCategory: ...
        }
    })
    .success(function(category,success) {                
        // Update TextBox fields
        $(".ajax").each(function(){
            $(this).val(category[$(this).attr("id")]);
        });
        //Other fields ...             
     })
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Get(string idCategory)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var _category = _categoryRepository.Get(Convert.ToInt16(idCategory));

         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
             return Json(_category);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         return Json(new Category());
     return View();
 }
```

**It´s working fine !**

But I´d like to know if it is the best way to do that... It is possible to do it another way? Maybe using Ajax.BeginForm?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: I'd stick with `jQuery.ajax()` as it's more flexible and less buggy. Good setup though

Comment: Any reason you have JSON and a View in the same action?

Comment: It's just for test purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways to do this in my view.

1) Return a partial view with the category fields in it each time you change the selected category in the grid. Don't bother with JSON.

2) If you want to use JSON (which is how I'd probably do it), then use a framework like [Knockout.JS](http://knockoutjs.com/) to handle the binding. It would look something like this:

```
<div id="current">
    Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"/><br/>
    Description: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click: Save" />
</div>

// javascript viewmodel w/ observable properties (except Id)
var Category = function(original) {
this.Id = original.Id;
this.Name = ko.observable(original.Name);
this.Description = ko.observable(original.Description);

this.asJson = function() {
    return {
        Id: this.Id,
        Name: this.Name(), // call observables as method to get underlying value
        Description: this.Description()
    };
};

this.Save = function() {
    $.post("/Category/Update", $.toJSON(this.asJson()));
};
}

$.post('/Category/Get', { idCategory: ... }, function(response) {
    var viewModel = new Category(response);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#current"));
}, "json");
```

Your action could probably be simplified to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Get(int idCategory)
{
    var category = _categoryRepository.Get(idCategory) ?? new Category();
    return Json(category)
}
```

Then to save just do whatever you normally do on the server

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Category updated)
{
    var category = _categoryRepository.Get(updated.Id);
    // todo: update category with values from updated model
}
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to call applyBindings multiple times, you can use templates instead. (I didn't test this code but it should be very close.)

```
<div id="current" data-bind="template: {name: 'categoryTemplate', data: Current}"/>
<input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click: Save" />

<script type="text/html" id="categoryTemplate">
    Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"/><br/>
    Description: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"/>
</script>

// javascript viewmodel w/ observable properties (except Id)
var Category = function(original) {
    this.Id = original.Id;
    this.Name = ko.observable(original.Name);
    this.Description = ko.observable(original.Description);

    this.asJson = function() {
        return {
            Id: this.Id,
            Name: this.Name(), // call observables as method to get underlying value
            Description: this.Description()
        };
    };
}

var viewModel = 
{
    Current = ko.observable({}),
    Save = function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/Category/Update", 
                data: $.toJSON(this.Current().asJson()),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
    }
};

$.post('/Category/Get', { idCategory: ... }, function(response) {
    viewModel.Current(new Category(response));
}, "json");

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#current"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I´ll take a look on Knockout JS...  And How about the Update funcion, Am I supposed to send each field property via ajax to controller?

Comment: Thanks Ryan!
Just one question:  With your sample, everytime the user select a category it creates a new viewmodel and execute ko.applyBinding... Is that correct? Am I supposed to applyBindings each grid select?

Comment: I know you shouldn't call applyBindings twice with the same model (it will double bind button click events) but I think it should work fine here since the model always changes. One alternative would be to use a template and a single observable property containing the response on the view model. I'll edit with a sample of that too.

Comment: Thanks so much Ryan! 
I´m only with a problem in the Update... When the controller´s Updated method is called, the category(parameter) is always blanked (Name = "", Description = "", Id = 0")... Do you have any idea what could it be?

Comment: Adding: contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to post method did the trick! Thanks

Comment: Hi Ryan, I´m trying to use the template, but without success... Is there any way to stick with your first suggestion, but without call multiple applyBindings?

Comment: Ok I looked into this. It's because I moved the Save function. You can't put the save button in the template now. It has to be outside it. Or I think you could move the Save function back to the Category type. Also, I typo'd the `data-bind` attribute on the template div. I also just changed the viewModel declaration to just be an object instead of a function.

Comment: If you want to see more thorough examples of Knockout templates you should check out the examples on the website and also look at Steve Sanderson's blog. There are some good links here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/links.html

Comment: Thanks for all help so far ! Now I´m getting the error : 
Error: Name is not defined
jquery.tmpl.js
Line: 362

Comment: Can you use Firebug to inspect `viewModel.Current().Name()`? As long as that is defined you should be able to bind to it. Possibly your return values from the server aren't getting assigned to Current?

Comment: The problem is the first time page is rendered, I dont have any grid´s category selected, so the viewModel.Current(new Category(response)); did not fire yet... So I have to create a Blank Category to start viewModel.Current, right?
Other question, after using Template, my TextBox have lost the jquery onFocus style... Any tip for that? Thanks

Comment: Yes you would need a blank Category if you want to show a default. I haven't tried using jquery's on focus, but I bet it's because the textbox is now inside of a script tag. You might make another question for it or ask on the KO mailing list.

Comment: Thanks! You are right about the script tag... In fact I dont need the template in that page, and it mess up all my html code... If I could do what you first suggest me without calling applyBidings every time would be great... Maybe there is a way to implement the template "Current" idea without using template?

Comment: I typically use templates for everything, but as a last ditch effort you might make Current an array and use the {{each}} syntax instead. You'll just have to clear it each time before adding the new Category. This example should help you get started: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I spotted one issue.
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#current"));
should be
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#current")[0]);
because without the [0] it doesn't give you a DOM node.

Comment: Really it should probably be `document.getElementById('current')`.